# How to get the number that is being dialed the , the outgoing number in android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-studio, telephony

I keep getting a value of null on the outgoing number I have tried a couple solutions from the web .

In my manifest I have these relevant lines

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" ></uses-permission>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" > </uses-permission>
  <receiver android:name=".home.OutgoingReceiver"  android:exported="true">
           <intent-filter>
               <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" >
                   <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />


               </action>
           </intent-filter>
       </receiver>
```

My receiver looks likes this , you will notice that I have been trying to retrieve the number in various ways here but I keep getting null value

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL)) {


            final String originalNumber = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER).toString();
            Log.d("APP", "outgoing,ringing:" + originalNumber);
        }
        String ph = intent.getExtras().getString(OutgoingReceiver.INTENT_PHONE_NUMBER);
        // savedNumber = intent.getExtras().getString("android.intent.extra.PHONE_NUMBER");
        String number = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);
        String phoneNumber = getResultData();
        if (phoneNumber == null) {
            // We could not find any previous data. Use the original phone number in this case.
            phoneNumber = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);
        }
        String phoneNumberTest = intent.getExtras().getString(OutgoingReceiver.INTENT_PHONE_NUMBER);
```

Answer (score 0):

First add this to your manifest:

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />
```

Then add this to your receiver:

```
if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL")) {
          String outoingNumber = intent.getExtras().getString("android.intent.extra.PHONE_NUMBER");
            return;
        }
```